# Порекомендуйте бесплатный хостинг MySQL (FREE HOSTING MYSQL)

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, бот

**Здравствуйте, я новый пользователь и хотел бы написать бота для проекта**

Моя проблема состоит из того что я сохраняю данные в JSON, но когда бот перезагружается ДатаБаза (т.е JSON) очищается.

Я пытался подключить MySQL через бесплатный хостинг 7м.пл (не реклама), но он не подключается... Выдаёт ошибку как на NodeJS, так и на Python.

Если вы знаете пожалуйста скажите, я буду очень рад! (И возможно поможете другим =))

P.s Если можно дайте пожалуйста код на Python =)

Comment: Для проекта можно использовать sqlite - там бд храниться в файле. Либо можно развернуть сервер на своём компьютере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример подключения будет такой

```
import mysql.connector

# Подключение к базе данных
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword",
  database="yourdatabase"
)

# Создание курсора
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Выполнение SQL-запроса
query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable"
cursor.execute(query)

# Получение результатов запроса
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Закрытие курсора и соединения
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Бесплатные хостинги - 000webhost, FreeMySQLHosting, InfinityFree